# backbone model event not firing

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-events

I'm using backbone with requirejs, I trigger an event on a global application object and set when the application start an handle but for some reason the event is not getting caught. Here is the code from the application:

main.js

```
require([
    "app",
    "router",
    "modules/facebookLogin"
],

function(app, Router,FacebookLogin) {

  // Define your master router on the application namespace and trigger all
    // navigation from this instance.
    app.router = new Router();
    app.currentFacebookSession = new FacebookLogin.Model();
    app.currentFacebookSession.on({
        'facebook:unauthorized': function () {
            //app.router.navigate('', true);
        },
        'facebook:disconnected': function () {
            //app.router.navigate('', true);
        },
        'facebook:connected': function () {
            //app.router.navigate('events', true);
            console.log('EVENTS');
        }
    });

  // Trigger the initial route and enable HTML5 History API support, set the
  // root folder to '/' by default.  Change in app.js.
  Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: app.root });
    //Init facebook
```

...

and the model is facebookLogin.js

```
// Facebookuser module
define(["app", "facebookSDK"],

// Map dependencies from above array.
function(app,FB) {

  // Create a new module.
  var FacebookLogin = app.module();

  // Default Model.
  FacebookLogin.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

      initialize: function (attributes, options) {
          options || (options = {});
          this.options = _.defaults(options, this.defaultOptions);
          this.facebookInitialize();
          _.bindAll(this, 'onLoginStatusChange');
         
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', this.onLoginStatusChange);
      },
.....

   onLoginStatusChange: function (response) {
          if (this._loginStatus === response.status) return false;

          var event;

          if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              event = 'facebook:unauthorized';
          } else if (response.status === 'connected') {
              event = 'facebook:connected';
              if (this.options.autoFetch === true) this.fetch();
          } else {
              event = 'facebook:disconnected';
          }

          this.trigger(event, this, response);
          this._loginStatus = response.status;
      },
```

On debug it comes to the trigger and run trigger with the following parameter.

```
 this.trigger(event, this, response);
```

this =

```
child
_changes: Object
_escapedAttributes: Object
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c0"
id: ""
onLoginStatusChange: function bound() {
options: Object
__proto__: Surrogate
```

event = `"facebook:connected"`

and the response is the right object

I replaced the app.Router.nagigate for now to debug the issue with a log but it never happens, Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the version of backbone I was using was not the one allowing multiple event binding via the on function.

Updated to 1.0.0 and works now.